# Can't find module 'react' while trying to test a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to add some tests to my application, but when I installed `react-testing-library` and `jest-dom`, I wrote this test, test if `componentDidMount` is called:

```
import { render } from "react-testing-library";

import { QuestionContainer } from "../containers/QuestionContainer";

it("should call componentDidMount", () => {
  const cDM = jest.spyOn(QuestionContainer.prototype, "componentDidMount");

  render(QuestionContainer);

  expect(cDM).toHaveBeenCalled(1);
});
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'react' from 'index.js'

However, Jest was able to find:
    '../containers/QuestionContainer.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].
```

I don't think that the file extension is problem..

Comment: You need to add `import React  from 'react'`

Comment: Tried that already.

Comment: and did you run `npm install`??

Comment: can you check if 'react' dependency exists in package.json.
Also check once if the extension for file QuestionContainer is .js or .jsx

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla I'll try now, I use `yarn`, but I'll try..

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari Yes, there is `react`

Comment: Try deleting your project's node_modules folder and then run `yarn cache clean` and `yarn` afterwards

Comment: Still not working!

Comment: Stupid mistake, I installed few dependencies in root folder instead of client folder where is React application.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have `react-test-renderer` installed:

`yarn add react-test-renderer` // or add it to your dev dependencies!